# Присвоить значение элементу массива PHP

Tags: php

Есть массив:

```
$arParams = array(
    'success_url' => 'example.com',
    'fail_url' => 'example.com',
    'status_url' => 'example.com',
    'reference' => array(
    'client_email' => $z_email
);
```

Мне нужно присвоить ключу `client_email` значение из переменной `$z_email`, которая объявлена ранее, в ней лежит значение из поля формы.
Как такое сделать?

Comment: Ну так `$arParams['client_email']=$z_email;`

Comment: Не работает. Там просто массив в массиве. Если присвоить, к примеру, ключу "fail_url" другие значение таким способом, то работает.

Comment: Я тупанул, не увидел, что там еще один массив `$arParams['reference']['client_email' ]= $z_email;`